# Convert ICON to HBITMAP to be displayed in popup menu?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, icons, gdi

I'm trying to [add bitmaps to a popup menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Using_Menu_Item_Bitmaps).

The problem I have is that I create my bitmaps from ICONs dynamically, and I have problems for 24bit color icons vs 24+alpha (32bit) color icons.

It seems that the bitmaps are only always drawn correctly when they are in 32bpp (including alpha channel).

Here's my (test) code:

```
void ConvertIconToBitmap(CBitmap& bmpObj, HICON hIcon, int cx, int cy, BOOL useDIB) {
    CClientDC screenDC(NULL);
    CBitmap bmpTmp;
    HANDLE_API_FAILURE( bmpTmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&screenDC, cx, cy) );
    CDC memDC;
    HANDLE_API_FAILURE( memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&screenDC) );
    CBitmap* pOldBmp = memDC.SelectObject(&bmpTmp);
    HANDLE_API_FAILURE( ::DrawIconEx( memDC.GetSafeHdc(), 0, 0, hIcon, cx, cy, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL) );
    memDC.SelectObject( pOldBmp );

    HBITMAP hDibBmp = (HBITMAP)::CopyImage((HANDLE)(HBITMAP)bmpTmp, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);

    HANDLE_API_FAILURE( hDibBmp );
    if (useDIB) {
        HANDLE_API_FAILURE( bmpObj.Attach(hDibBmp) ); // works for 32bit/transparanecy
    } else {
        HANDLE_API_FAILURE( bmpObj.Attach(bmpTmp.Detach()) ); // works for 24bit
    }
}

...
    CMenu menu;
    menu.LoadMenu(IDR_POPUPMENU);
    CMenu* pMenu = menu.GetSubMenu(0);

    int cx, cy;
    cx = cy = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMENU);
    MENUITEMINFO mii;
    mii.cbSize = sizeof mii;
    mii.fMask = MIIM_BITMAP;

    HICON pwdIco = ExtractIcon(NULL/*=current instance*/, L"path/to/file.exe", 0);

    // If icon is 32bit-alpha this works, but doesn't work with 24bit icon
    CBitmap bmpTop;
    ConvertIconToBitmap(bmpTop, pwdIco, cx, cy, TRUE);
    mii.hbmpItem = bmpTop;
    pMenu->SetMenuItemInfo(ID_MENU_TOP, &mii, FALSE);

    // If icon is 32bit-alpha transparent areas are shown in black, but 24bit icon is also displayed correctly
    CBitmap bmpApp;
    ConvertIconToBitmap(bmpApp, pwdIco, cx, cy, FALSE);
    HBITMAP bmpTransp = bmpApp;
    mii.hbmpItem = bmpTransp;
    pMenu->SetMenuItemInfo(ID_MENU_TEST, &mii, FALSE);


    this->ClientToScreen(&point);
    pMenu->TrackPopupMenu(nFlags, point.x, point.y, this);
```

Since I need to dynamically populate the menu entries images from existing file's icons, I can't just statically fiddle out the bitmaps and use these instead of icons.

What are the requirements for the `HBITMAP` passed in the `hbmpItem` member of the [MENUITEMINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure passed to [SetMenuItemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ???

And how do I make sure the bitmap "created" with `DrawIconEx` does fulfill these requirements?

---

Oh, and to my great pleasure I just learned that 32-bit alpha-blended menu item bitmaps don't work at under Windows XP (transparent=black there), so I'll have to map transparency myself somehow it seems. (Possibly by replacing some color with `GetSysColor(COLOR_MENU)`.)

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsuidevelopment/thread/b3dde0f6-b20b-4a96-885e-f72bad3a2ae6

Comment: Seems like a case of winapi-insanity: http://www.nanoant.com/programming/themed-menus-icons-a-complete-vista-xp-solution

Comment: I'd recommend switching to GDI+. The library is much better at handling different types of images.

Comment: @snowdude - My research so far leads me to believe that the problem is less the images, but more the Menu and how it displays bitmap: Change btw. XP and Vista / Issues if image isn't 32bpp, etc. I'm not sure that GDI+ would help here.

Comment: You could owner-draw the menu, rendering the icons directly, rather than trying to convert them to bitmaps.